# How to concatenate password with mysql:// protocol in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

I have a password that contains "]" so rebol doesn't accept mysql://user:password

How to concatenate a string with mysql:// ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [block form](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-13.html#section-2.2) to open the port:

```
my-database: open [
    scheme: 'mysql
    host: "localhost"
    user: "user"
    pass: "pass"
    path: "/dbpath"
]
```

You can examine output from the `DECODE-URL` function to see how Rebol turns a URL into a port specification:

```
probe decode-url foo://bar:baz@foobar.qux:999/quux
```